# How to add chained dropdown filter to a wordpress website

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a download page http://megawatershedcg.in/dprs/ where i have table with list files for download.. while uploading the form m adding details to it like of which district, block and gp that files belong to. When user select the first dropdown where he will be selecting the district and block... Next dropdown should load only that particular gp's that belong to that district. I have no knowledge of wordpress coding i have only used plugins. What are the possible solutions to it.

Comment: It sounds like you need to work out what code is needed to make the dropdowns work conditionally. It will depend on how you store the files (Media Library?) and how you flag them as belonging to a certain district/gp. You might need to build a custom post type to house them, then add a custom taxonomy for each level (district/gp), all as part of a custom plugin. You could then make either a shortcode or a block to drop into the page showing the info, and that shortcode or block would have the JS or PHP needed to make the dropdowns conditional.

Comment: i have already made custom post type and custom taxomony for both district and gp. but m unable to do the js part. i have also added the shortcode and the drop down is working but the data within the second dropdown is not filtered according to my previous selection

Comment: Since your question seems JS-specific you may have better luck finding answers on StackOverflow. You'll want to share your code since the classes, IDs, structure will all determine how you can go about making it interactive.

Comment: i have a bit of knowledge about JS.. i have no info about wordpress actually..  can you help me on how to find the classes and id of the dropdown that is made through plugin. and how m i determine the database and find the right place to apply js

Comment: You said you made the CPT, the taxonomy, and the shortcode. That means you are the one who has added (or not added) classes and ID of the dropdown. No one can help if you're not sharing your code, and on this site it's unlikely to get much assistance with JS as the topics are intended to be WordPress-specific.